# Merge two multiline strings like git does

Tags: python, text, merge, diff

I'd like to 'combine' two (usually very similar) multiline strings (close to, what `git` does, when it merges changes on files).

Something like

```
>>> combine([
    'Hello,',
    'this is a text hat has been altered on one place',
    'while altered differently on another',],[
    'Hello,',
    'this is another text hat has been altered on a different place',
    'while altered differently on another',])
['Hello,',
 'this is another text hat has been altered on a different place',
 'this is a text hat has been altered on one place',
 'while altered differently on another',]
```

I don't have enough information for a three-way-diff so I'd like to find similarities and make sure no lines get lost.

I found several manual approaches using `set` and so on. But I need a way to keep **order**, **similar sections** and multiple occurrences of identical (i.e empty) lines.

Is there a 'pythonic' (short, elegant, sophisticated) way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have two elements only(lists), this should work:

```
def combine(target):
  return target[0]+list(x for x in target[1] if x not in target[0])
```

This adds the first item with elements that are in the second item but not in the first.

**Later edit:**

I haven't used `difflib` a lot, but it gives the correct result for me.

```
import difflib

def merge_text(text1:str, text2:str) -> str:
    return "\n".join(
        line[2:] for line in difflib.Differ().compare(
            text1.split("\n"),
            text2.split("\n")) 
        if not line.startswith("?"))
```

Comment: I've modified my example to make sure I'm talking about lines of a written text (order is important). So making sure all lines are present is not enough - some lines (like empty ones) can even appear more than once.

Comment: @frans : much obliged!